# Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory :ubuntu ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, next.js

I was trying to run a nextjs application on **t2.small ec2** instance of aws on ubuntu server.When i run command "npm run dev" it works perfectly fine and the application runs on public ip address.But when i tried to run command "npm run build" after sometime it deprecated the event by ending it with ..Killed.Then i tried some solutions from here and there and finally got an error saying:"**Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory**" on npm run build command.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Run your `npm run build` with `--max-old-space-size=2048` parameter which allows it to use more memory.

```
node --max-old-space-size=2048 npm run build
```